# django saving the wrong time in database

Tags: python, django, django-models

so it's my how I updated my queryset of one of the models in my code:

```
journal.update(**new_)
```

and new_ is a dictionary with name and values of the fields which I want to update. But when I set the dictionary something like:

```
new_ = {
    'symbol': <Symbols: btc>,
    'status': 'o',
    'side': 'l',
    'open_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 1, 11, 52),
    'entry_price': '995945994564156'
}
```

It's setting the wrong time on the database.

For this example it's setting it as `2023-06-01 08:22:00` which is *-3:30* less than what I sent... the timezone I used is *UTC+3:30*

and it's the field in my Journal model:

```
open_date = models.DateTimeField(
    default=timezone.localtime(timezone.now()),
    editable=False
)
```

I tried changing the format of the datetime but still didn't work...

Comment: can you show what it gives you back with the query as well? basically it is giving you the time in utc ... and it is up to you to relocalize it...afaik there is some way to specify a that it store the datetimes as naive (without timezone) or in a different timezone

Comment: you are learning a lesson... though it appears simple ... time and especially timezones suck and are hard

Comment: @JoranBeasley I solved the problem by adding  'TIME_ZONE': 'Asia/Tehran' in the DATABASES in settings.py.but what do you recommend instead of using datetime?

Comment: no datetime is the right choice ... im just sayinmg time in general is something that appears simple but has alot of gotchas

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to change DATABASES in settings.py like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'TIME_ZONE': 'Asia/Tehran',
    }
}
```

and the problem is solved.